# Have to click twice to run a function via Bootstrap buttons plugin

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Why I have to click twice to run a function that uses `active` class added by Bootstrap buttons plugin?

```
var monthly = $("input[name='montly_total']");
var once = $("input[name='once_total']");

$(".button-selector").click(function () {
 $(".button-selector.monthly.active").sum("click", monthly);
 $(".button-selector.once.active").sum("click", once)
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ynts/3Z6sm/. Inputs are updated only on a second click on a button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those buttons are a [pain to use](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2380), because they don't fire any custom event you can hook your functionality onto.

That said, here's an ugly `setTimeout()` workaround:

```
$(".button-selector").click(function () {
    // break out of click handler chain
    setTimeout(function() {
        // by the time this runs, the active state will have been updated
        $(".button-selector.monthly.active").sum("click", monthly);
        $(".button-selector.once.active").sum("click", once)
    }, 0);
});
```

Comment: @pktangyue The value `0` is the lowest value that `setTimeout()` will accept; as mentioned in the comments, it breaks the chain of click handlers (i.e. the click handler of bootstrap gets called afterwards, and only then the code inside the `setTimeout()`.

Comment: but can `0` make sure it will be called after bootstrap all the time? Is it possible the function in `setTimeout` to be called first?

Comment: @pktangyue JavaScript is single threaded, so the code inside `setTimeout()` only runs when the control is handed back to the browser (i.e. idling), which is after all the click handlers have finished.

Comment: the last question, if I write 2 `setTimeout(function(){XXX},0)`, can they be called by order? thanks

Comment: @pktangyue That behaviour would (I think) be undefined, so don't rely on that.